# Использование нативных библиотек для Android программирования.

Tags: android, android-ndk

Всем добрый день, хотел спросить, где можно взять информацию по использованию нативных библиотек для Android программирования.

Интересует использование кода как из командной строки, так и именно библиотек.

Совсем идеально было бы увидеть примеры.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android NDK включает ряд примеров, которых обычно достаточно, чтобы подключать свои собственные библиотеки. Они хранятся в папке NDK (<ndk>/samples). Описания примеров есть на оффициальном сайте: [Sample applications](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples).

По поводу командной строки: выполняется с помощью вызова `system(cmd)` в C/C++ или `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` в Java.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а не знаете ещё, как работает функция void loadLibrary(String libName), если она подгружает библиотеку, то как с ней потом работать? Ни хэндла, ни чего-то другого не возвращается...

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду функцию Java System.loadLibrary, то вам нужно объявить в C/C++ коде функции согласно спецификации JNI и прямо вызывать их своего кода. Это проще всего понять, посмотрев пример hello-jni - там всего одна функция.